# Can my company use our Google accounts to sign into a custom web application

Tags: cakephp, single-sign-on

My company uses Google web apps for our e-mails and documents. I have made a web application for processing orders using cakePHP. Is it possible for me to allow my sales guys sign into the application using their Google account (work account only) instead of having to create a new account in my cakePHP application.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Google is an OpenId provider, so you just need to implement an OpenId consumer.

You can get [sample code from the OpenId website](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/). And you can improve the usability of the sign in form with a [jQuery OpenId Plugin](http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Jquery-Simple-Openid/).

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that I can see that would suit your needs would be [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) although I've had little experience with it. It allows you to share a singular digital identity. Have a look at this [CakePHP and OpenID article.](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/06/new-version-of-the-openid-component/)

Comment: I've looked at that article (and the updated code for it) and am unable to get it working. I am trying some other work arounds and even trying some OpenID PHP classes outside of cake to try and get this working as a proof of concept, but no luck getting any of these to work yet. I am going to try it some more today.

Comment: I still have not gotten this to work. If anyone has a real working example of this, I would love to see it.

Comment: I've not had too much experience with Cake but if you would like more responses and help you'd probably be better off with stating what your problem is rather than saying 'am unable to get it working'. There's not much anyone can do other than ask you what the problem is.